# How to remove old app version's analytics data from Google Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

***Intro:***
Hi, I have an app that is connected to Google Analytics.

Previously, it was built using **React Native** and Now I've made using **Flutter** & published it with version code: 3.0.1+. and all the services connected with the old app are down.

***Problem:***
But I am getting analytics data of old versions also. I want to remove/disconnect those old versions from Google Analytics.

To get the correct data, I need to use filters every time to see the correct analytics.
I know about the custom reports, but I want to know, how I can delete or remove old versions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, we would point a new app to a new property if we don't want to mix the data. Old app's performance is important to have if we want to compare certain metrics with a new app.

You can, however, file a [data deletion request](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9940393?hl=en) and have the old data deleted.